# Delete CSRF cookie on submit form success

Tags: security, csrf

I need to delete the `CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN` cookie when a form submission reaches certain/success page. I'm using [CSRF](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#csrfTokenName) stripped cookie's value to store entry title like this:

```
{% set token = craft.request.csrfToken[:10]|replace({'~':'P', '_':'B', '|':'T'})|upper %}
```

Upon succesful form submission I'd like to erase cookie name `CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN` and it's value so on next form load there is a new cookie value set for `CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN` name to prevent next entry to be stored/updated in the same entry.

Trying to achieve this I've failed right after accessing to `csrfTokenName`.

```
Neither the property "csrfTokenName" nor one of the methods
"csrfTokenName()", "getcsrfTokenName()"/"iscsrfTokenName()" or "__call()" 
exist and have public access in class "Craft\HttpRequestVariable"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guesss this could be accomplished using the [cookies plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/cookies) or a simple [jquery cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library like js-cookie.

This is how you would go about it with the cookies plugin: set the cookies name without any value:

```
{{ setCookie( NAME ) }}
```

Comment: The @khalwat 's cookies plugin helped.